# flutter firebase get all documents' field of type array

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter project where I display the products and their info, but in firebase, I converted the image type from string to an array and faced an issue due to type changing. In another class, I have the same example but it's restricted to one document only, which won't apply to my case.

```
void getImage() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Product')
        .doc(docID)
        .get()
        .then((document) {
      imageLists = document.data()['image'];
    });
  }
```

Is there anyway to make this code accept array type?

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: product.snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Flexible(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                        gridDelegate:
                            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                        ),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 16, 8, 0),
                            child: Image.network(
                              // here
                              snapshot.data.docs[index].get('image'),
                              width: 150,
                              height: 120,
                            ),
                          );                             
                        }),
                  );
                }
              }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found a solution replace this code:

```
snapshot.data.docs[index].get('image'),
```

with this

```
snapshot.data.docs[index]['image'][0],
```

The problem was the first code accepts only string type, by adding the field in array brackets it knows the type is an array and adding an additional brackets for the array index.